# Eval-ing a function

Tags: javascript, browser, node.js, eval, web-worker

I am trying to create a small library that you can send an object(that has functions) and some data, and args, and it will send the object, data, and args to a worker process who will then eval the object to reconstruct the functions(from strings to functions)

Currently I have this:

`JSON.stringify(object, function(key, val) {
if typeof val === 'function' { return val + '' }
return val
});`

This function will stringify an object including functions.

In my worker I am trying to undo this process.

I have tried the following:
`eval(object)`
I have also tried implementing JSON.parse with trying to eval() each function when I come across one.

I have also tried `eval("return " + object.function)`

Is this possible?

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to use eval.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I mean the problem behind this problem.

Comment: I am trying to distribute calculations across webworkers. But a lot of the time I don't know what the calculation is until the moment I need to do it.

Comment: You'd be better off requiring your calculation library in both the master and the worker, and just passing the name of the calculation function to the worker.  You can then just execute the calc function in the worker by doing `calcLibrary[funcName]();`

Comment: @Jeff Is this library public?

Comment: Yes, although in its infancy. https://github.com/ChromoX/finance.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
eval("(" + object.function + ")");
```

You cannot put a return statement just somewhere.

`function() {}` is evaluated as a function *declaration*, which fails because it has no name. Since the data to be parsed represents a function *expression*, like `var f = function() {}`, you need to put `()` around it, so that it is evaluated as an expression.